# Reselect items in Calendar after processing the items

Tags: vba, outlook, calendar, appointment

I have an Outlook VBA function that takes a Selection and processes its Items.

I want it to Select again whatever Selection existed previously.

I guessed I have to store the initial selection. After processing a first item, the Selection becomes empty, so I would use `AddToSelection` to add one item at a time.
But I could not avoid getting `error 438`.

From [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.addtoselection), the only possible source of error I see is any listed in "Under the following conditions, Outlook returns an error when you call the AddToSelection method:"
But I think none of those apply.

**What are possible sources of error, and how can I systematically assess which is my case?**

**How can I end with a `Selection` of the same original items?**

My function (here applied to a `Selection` with a single item):

```
Sub MoveAppt()
' Move selected appointment a given number of days within the Calendar
    Dim sel As Outlook.Selection, xpl As Explorer
    Dim oOlAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Set xpl = Application.ActiveExplorer
    Set sel = xpl.Selection
    Set oOlAppt = sel.Item(1)
    Dim newStart As Date
    Dim ndays As Integer
    ndays = 7
    newStart = MoveAppointment(oOlAppt, ndays)

    Debug.Print "Count = " & xpl.Selection.Count    ' THIS GIVES 0, CONFIRMING AN EMPTY Selection
    If (xpl.IsItemSelectableInView(oOlAppt)) Then   ' <----- THIS RETURNS True ...
        xpl.AddToSelection oOlAppt                  ' <----- ... BUT THIS GIVES ERROR -2147467259 (80004005)
    Else
        Debug.Print "Object is not selectable"
    End If
End Sub

Function MoveAppointment(ByRef oOlAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem, ByVal ndays As Integer) As Date
' Move an Outlook.AppointmentItem a given number of days within the Calendar
    With oOlAppt
        Dim currStart As Date, newStart As Date
        currStart = .Start
        newStart = DateAdd("d", ndays, currStart)
        .Start = newStart
        .Save
    End With
    MoveAppointment2 = newStart
End Function
```

**EDIT**:
Removing parenthesis about the argument of `AddToSelection` changed the error to that indicated in the code.
So I tried: 1) setting a breakpoint at that line, 2) when the breakpoint is hit, going in the calendar view to the week of `newStart`, where the moved item is now, 3) continuing. This runs ok, so it seems to answer the question.

As for how to re-select the original items, I guess I should: 1) determine the min and max dates among all original items, 2) set the `CalendarView` to cover those dates, 3) loop through all items in the original selection and `AddToSelection` them.
I wouldn't know if there is anything simpler.

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Add code for calling the function and for MoveAppointment.

Comment: `xpl.AddToSelection apptmts`. No brackets around apptmts and later around oOlAppt

Comment: The real question appears to be, why are the selected items being deselected in MoveAppointment?

Comment: @niton - #1: Created a MCVE.

Comment: @niton - #2: Done. That changes the error code, to something more sensible, and it helped revealing another problem, which is solved. Please see EDIT.

Comment: @niton - #3: Agreed. But that is the way Outlook works, and then my need for writing code to re-select items.

Comment: The selection is no longer in the ActiveExplorer. You have `Set sel = xpl.Selection` to keep a handle on the selection. Replace `Debug.Print "Count = " & xpl.Selection.Count` with `Debug.Print "Count = " & sel.Count`. The reason xpl.Selection.Count returns zero is `sel` has moved outside of the active explorer.

Comment: @niton - That would only print the original number of selected items, but it would not solve my problem. I need to end with the same original set of appointments selected.

Comment: `Debug.Print "Count = " & sel.Count` prints the count of the **current** number of selected items. The original selected items have not been deselected they have moved out of view. Change your calendar view so there are two weeks visible, before making a selection in the first week. You should see the selection end up in the second week. You can use this awkward method to get xpl.Selection (ActiveExplorer.Selection) again, or just use the existing `sel` for whatever purpose you want xpl.Selection for.

Comment: @niton - I think this is not true. `Debug.Print "Count = " & sel.Count` prints the count of items at the time `Set sel = xpl.Selection` was executed, and it wouldn't change if I later change the `xpl.Selection`.
On the ohter hand, `Debug.Print "Count = " & xpl.Selection.Count` prints the count of the current number of selected items.
I have just tested this.
Then the need of re-selecting items.

Answer (score 0):

Re: How can I end with a Selection of the same original items?

With `Set sel = xpl.Selection`, sel is a Selection of the same original items.

```
Sub MoveAppt_SelOnly()

    ' Move selected appointment a given number of days within the Calendar

    Dim xpl As Explorer
    Dim sel As Selection
    Dim ndays As Long

    Set xpl = ActiveExplorer

    If xpl.Selection(1).Class = olAppointment Then

        If xpl.Selection(1).subject = "test" Then

            Debug.Print
            Debug.Print "xpl.Selection.count ....: " & xpl.Selection.count
            Debug.Print "xpl.Selection(1).subject: " & xpl.Selection(1).subject
            Debug.Print "xpl.Selection(1).start..: " & xpl.Selection(1).Start

            Set sel = xpl.Selection
            Debug.Print "sel(1).subject..........: " & sel(1).subject
            Debug.Print "sel(1).start............: " & sel(1).Start

            ndays = 7

            MoveAppointment sel(1), ndays

            Debug.Print
            Debug.Print "xpl.Selection.count ....: " & xpl.Selection.count
            Debug.Print "sel(1).subject..........: " & sel(1).subject
            Debug.Print "sel(1).start.........new: " & sel(1).Start

            ' For testing. Be sure the item is not in the view after this first move
            '  otherwise you do not lose track of xpl.Selection.
            MsgBox "The moved item should not be in the view." & vbCr & _
                "xpl.Selection.count ....: " & xpl.Selection.count & vbCr & _
                "sel(1).subject..........: " & sel(1).subject & vbCr & _
                "sel(1).start.........new: " & sel(1).Start

            Debug.Print
            ' If you see zero here it does not matter
            Debug.Print "xpl.Selection.count ....: " & xpl.Selection.count

            Debug.Print "sel(1).subject..........: " & sel(1).subject
            Debug.Print "sel(1).start.........new: " & sel(1).Start

            ' Return the item to where it started, using sel,
            '   a "Selection of the same original items".
            MoveAppointment sel(1), ndays * (-1)

            MsgBox "The moved item should be in the view now." & vbCr & _
                "xpl.Selection.count ....: " & xpl.Selection.count & vbCr & _
                "sel(1).subject..........: " & sel(1).subject & vbCr & _
                "sel(1).start....original: " & sel(1).Start

            Debug.Print
            ' If you see zero here it does not matter
            Debug.Print "xpl.Selection.count ....: " & xpl.Selection.count

            Debug.Print "sel(1).subject..........: " & sel(1).subject
            Debug.Print "sel(1).start....original: " & sel(1).Start

        End If

    End If

End Sub


Sub MoveAppointment(ByRef oOlAppt As AppointmentItem, ByVal ndays As Long)

    ' Move an AppointmentItem a given number of days within the Calendar

    Dim newStart As Date

    With oOlAppt
        oOlAppt.Start = DateAdd("d", ndays, oOlAppt.Start)
        .Save
    End With

End Sub
```